# Either my if statement or parameter doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, parameters, puppeteer

Helloo! I have been trying to make a Walmart stock monitor, but I ran into an issue, but realized that redirecting to the desired link again fixes the issue therefore in my code. I try to catch the error that lets me identify the error and then run the original function again, but with the parameter that sets `a=1` so that it triggers the if statement causing it to refresh to go to the desired page and check stock again, but its not working how I desired, it appears that the parameter `a` always gets set to `0` and I have no clue why, id gladly appreciate any help !

```
const core = require('puppeteer-core');

async function init(a) {
  let b = a;
  console.log(b);
  const browser = await core.launch({
    executablePath: '/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: [
      '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
      '--accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9',
      '--sec-fetch-site=none',
    ],
  });

  const page = (await browser.pages())[0];

  await page.goto(
    'https://www.walmart.com/ip/POP-Rocks-BTS-Jungkook/406893736'
  );
  if (a == 1) {
    reload(page);
    stockChecker();
    console.log(a);
  } else {
    console.log(`testing...${a}`);
    stockChecker(page);
    console.log('LfdlA');
  }
}

async function stockChecker(page) {
  let stock = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let in_out_of_stock = document.querySelector(
      'link[itemprop="availability"]'
    ).href;

    return in_out_of_stock;
  });

  let seller = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let seller = document.querySelector('.seller-name').innerText;
    return seller;
  });

  if (
    stock.toLowerCase().includes('instock') &&
    seller.toLowerCase().includes('walmart')
  ) {
    return console.log('in stock');
  } else {
    return console.log('out of stock');
  }
}

async function reload(page) {
  await page.goto(
    'https://www.walmart.com/ip/POP-Rocks-BTS-Jungkook/406893736'
  );
}

async function run() {
  let a = 0;
  try {
    await init(a);
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.toString().toLowerCase().includes("'href' of null")) {
      a = 1;
      init(a);
      console.log(a);
    } else {
      console.log(e.toString());
    }
  }
}

run();
```

Also I am very new to using puppeteer if you recommend any other web automation frameworks that are better in terms of speed / effectiveness  or see any ways for me to refactor my code id gladly appreciate that as well comrades.

Comment: Can you add the error stack? As I can see the first time `a set to 1` and it should go to the `else` ? Is it not going there? I am not following it.

Comment: ```testing...0
(node:40736) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of null
```
This is my console, I know how to handle this error, it isn't a problem but when a should equal 1, it equals 0 which I don't know why.

Comment: Yeah I dont get it either ;-;

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to answer my question but I was able to solve my problem, all I did was put all my functions in one so that all variables were shared and I could easily control things such a page go to.

```
async function init() {
  const browser = await core.launch({
    executablePath: '/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: [
      '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
      '--accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9',
      '--sec-fetch-site=none',
    ],
  });

  const page = (await browser.pages())[0];

  await page.goto(
    'https://www.walmart.com/ip/POP-Rocks-BTS-Jungkook/406893736'
  );

  // Functions

  async function reload() {
    await page.goto(
      'https://www.walmart.com/ip/POP-Rocks-BTS-Jungkook/406893736'
    );
  }

  async function stockChecker() {
    let stock = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let in_out_of_stock = document.querySelector(
        'link[itemprop="availability"]'
      ).href;

      return in_out_of_stock;
    });

    let seller = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let seller = document.querySelector('.seller-name').innerText;
      return seller;
    });

    if (
      stock.toLowerCase().includes('instock') &&
      seller.toLowerCase().includes('walmart')
    ) {
      return console.log('in stock');
    } else {
      return console.log('out of stock');
    }
  }

  // run code

  try {
    await stockChecker();
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.toString().toLowerCase().includes("'href' of null")) {
      reload();
      stockChecker();
    } else {
      console.log(e.toString());
    }
  }
}

init();
```

Comment: This is not the problem, it might occur because of the scoping you have created. I hope my answers will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem actually when I try to see different pieces of code, errors are only handled at one place. It is you catch block which is causing an issue.

Step 1: when you run the code `a` value is `0` and it is being passed correctly to the function `init`, but in the init function something breaks i.e throwing an error and you haven't handled any errors in the `init` function which changes the flow of execution and invoke the catch from `run` function. When your catch is being executed your are assigning `a=1` which runs the code again with value `a`. I am adding a code for future reference to add the catch block with every function to debugger things better.

```
const core = require('puppeteer-core');

async function init(a) {
  let b = a;
  console.log(b);
try {
  const browser = await core.launch({
    executablePath: '/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: [
      '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
      '--accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9',
      '--sec-fetch-site=none',
    ],
  });

  const page = (await browser.pages())[0];

  await page.goto(
    'https://www.walmart.com/ip/POP-Rocks-BTS-Jungkook/406893736'
  );
  if (a == 1) {
    reload(page);
    stockChecker();
    console.log(a);
  } else {
    console.log(`testing...${a}`);
    stockChecker(page);
    console.log('LfdlA');
  }
 } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Error occurred in init function ${e}`);
 }
}

async function stockChecker(page) {

try {
  let stock = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let in_out_of_stock = document.querySelector(
      'link[itemprop="availability"]'
    ).href;

    return in_out_of_stock;
  });

  let seller = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let seller = document.querySelector('.seller-name').innerText;
    return seller;
  });

  if (
    stock.toLowerCase().includes('instock') &&
    seller.toLowerCase().includes('walmart')
  ) {
    return console.log('in stock');
  } else {
    return console.log('out of stock');
  }
  } catch (e) {console.error(`Error occurred in stock method ${e}`)};
}

async function reload(page) {
 try {
      await page.goto(
    'https://www.walmart.com/ip/POP-Rocks-BTS-Jungkook/406893736'
     );
    } catch (e) {console.error(`Error occurred in reload function ${e}`)}
}

async function run() {
  let a = 0;
  try {
    await init(a);
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.toString().toLowerCase().includes("'href' of null")) {
      a = 1;
      init(a);
      console.log(a);
    } else {
      console.log(e.toString());
    }
  }
}

run();
```

It is always good to handle errors when they occur instead allow them to propagate upwards in the code as it might force the code to behave unexpectedly.